# Adding Data to a Calendar created in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

have created the pictured calendar on new tab within the same spreadsheet on Google Sheets. However, I am having a very hard time successfully transferring the data onto the actual calendar.

I am attempting to automatically have the sum of the "Total R" column entered into the calendar for the specific date. For example, February 14th would display "-0.16".

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]I

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/171502/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter()`, like this:

```
=iferror(sum(filter( 
  TradeList!$F$2:$F, 
  TradeList!$A$2:$A = value(to_text(C7) & to_text($D$1))
)))
```

See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197).

Comment: Hi @doubleunary - thanks a ton for replying. I entered the code as follows in the picture I added to the original post and am not getting any results. It doesn't say there is any error, just nothing shows up. Anything you see I can change?

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: After trying multiple times I could not get the blank sheet working - so I just made a new public editable spreadsheet - any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gZFzyIdelkMPZSyTZnURAuch9UAzRbunVrL52uaimAE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The formula seems to work fine. The month at the top is not in cell `D1` but in the merged cell `A1` so you only need to adjust that. See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gZFzyIdelkMPZSyTZnURAuch9UAzRbunVrL52uaimAE/edit#gid=1503774518).